# Lock-free cache implementation in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, caching, lock-free

Is there any way in C++11 to implement a lock-free cache for an object, which would be safe to access from multiple threads? The calculation I'm looking to cache isn't super cheap but also isn't super expensive, so requiring a lock would defeat the purpose of caching in my case. IIUC, `std::atomic` isn't guaranteed to be lock-free.

Edit: Since calculate isn't -too- expensive, I actually don't mind if it runs once or twice too many. But I -do- need to make sure all consumers get the correct value. In the naive example below, this isn't guaranteed because due to memory re-ordering it's possible for a thread to get an uninitialized value of `m_val` since another thread set `m_alreadyCalculated` to true, but didn't set `m_val`'s value yet.

Edit2: The comments below point out that for basic types, `std::atomic` would probably be lock free. In case it is, what's the correct way in the example below of using C++11's memory ordering to make sure it isn't possible for `m_alreadyCalculated` to be set to true before `m_val`'s value is set?

Non-thread-safe cache example:

```
class C {
public:
   C(int param) : m_param(param) {}

   getValue() {
      if (!m_alreadyCalculated) {
          m_val = calculate(m_param);
          m_alreadyCalculated = true;
      }
      return m_val;
   }

   double calculate(int param) {
       // Some calculation
   }

private:
   int m_param;
   double m_val;
   bool m_alreadyCalculated = false;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like quite specific application, so do you care if `std::atomic` is guaranteed to be lock free, or do you just care that it is lock free on your intended platform(s) and compiler(s)?

Comment: Anyway, if benefit of the cache is so small, that using a mutex defeats the purpose of it, then using a spin lock would probably be feasible.

Comment: I need std::atomic to be guaranteed lock-free.

Comment: Formally, `std::atomic<T>` isn't required to be lock-free, but for "ordinary" types `T` on just about any platform you'll encounter today, it is lock-free. And you can check that with the `atomic_is_lock_free` functions or their member-function variants.

Answer (score 2):

Consider something as:

```
class C {
public:
   double getValue() {
      if (alreadyCalculated == true)
         return m_val;

      bool expected = false;
      if (calculationInProgress.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true)) {
         m_val = calculate(m_param);
         alreadyCalculated = true;
      // calculationInProgress = false;
      }
      else {
     //  while (calculationInProgress == true)
         while (alreadyCalculated == false)
            ; // spin
      }
      return m_val;
   }

private:
   double m_val;
   std::atomic<bool> alreadyCalculated {false};
   std::atomic<bool> calculationInProgress {false};
};
```

It's not in fact lock-free, there is a spin lock inside. But I think you cannot avoid such a lock if you don't want to run `calculate()` by multiple threads.

`getValue()` gets more complicated here, but the important part is that once `m_val` is calculated, it will always return immediately in the first `if` statement.

**UPDATE**

For performance reasons, it might also be a good idea do pad the whole class to a cache line size.

**UPDATE 2**

There was a bug in the original answer, thanks JVApen to pointing this out (it's marked by comments). The variable `calculationInProgress` would be better renamed to something as `calculationHasStarted`.

Also, please note that this solution assumes that `calculate()` does not throw an exception.

Comment: Actually, I don't really mind if calculate() runs once or twice too many, since it's not -very- expensive. I just don't want to run it more times than necessary. I've edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: It only matters in the _not-yet-calculated_ part of `getValue()`, you would still need to protect the update of `m_val` somehow. This solution is IMO more elegant than to invoke `calculate()` multiple times, which would bring no benefit here. Crucial is to run `getValue()` as quickly as possible once the value is calculated.

Comment: Because it is written by one thread a read by others. Without atomics, it would be a data race.

Comment: But I don't see how making it atomic helps. Actually, it looks like it is still possible for m_val to to be uninitialized when alreadyCalculated is already true, in case the memory is reordered. I know atomics let you avoid such memory re-ordering, but do you get it here by default?

Comment: I believe so, since the `alreadyCalculated=true;` statement should generate memory fence.

Comment: You can still have races in this code, removing calculateInProgress = false can fix that issue

Comment: @JVApen Can you please specify these races? I don't see them. However, thanks to your note, I realized that the solution can be simplified, I've updated the code via comments.

Comment: Consider two threads paused on initing expected. If one continues an goes through the calculation, it sets alreadyCalculated to false, making the second thread calculating the same thing. As alreadyCalculated is true, every other thread can read m_val, while you are assigning it a second time. Even though it shoul be the same value, you still have a race.

Comment: @daniel: I know performance is important, though I usually keep myself to the rule: if multithreaded isn't 100% clear when you look at it, rewrite it. There is nothing as worse as spending days looking for races. You better loose some performance compared to chaising ghosts. In this case you have two atomics guarding the calculation in which case order becomes very important. Make sure you understand that (for 100%) before using!

Comment: No one ever sets `alreadyCalculated` to `false`, except of its initialization, at least according to the code in the question. The required value is calculated only once in the lifetime of an instance of `C`. Otherwise, we are talking about completely different cases and then, of course, a solution would need to be different as well.

Comment: @JVApen What do you mean by "initing expected"? `expected` is a local variable of `getValue()`, threfore a private local variable for each thread.

Comment: I just meant the location, the thing is that you can have 2 threads calculating/assigning. Its hard to explain, let me try to draw it later on.

Comment: @JVApen I see, you wrote "it sets alreadyCalculated to false" but likely meant "it sets calculationInProgress to false". Then, you were right. Anyway the new version should work correctly, it sets both atomic flags only once to `true` in a lifetime of a `C` instance and never back to `false`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107453/discussion-between-jvapen-and-daniel-langr).

Answer (score 0):

std::atomic is not guaranteed to be lock-free, though you can check on `std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free()` or `std::atomic::is_always_lock_free()` to see if your implementation can do this lockfree.

Another approach could be using `std::call_once`, however from my understanding this is even worse as it is meant to block the other threads.

So, in this case, I would go with the std::atomic for both m_val and alreadyCalculated. Which contains the risk that 2 (or more) threads are calculating the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer the one technical question here: To make sure the value is updated before the flag, you update the flag with release semantics. The meaning of release semantics is that this update must (be seen as) happen after all previous ones. On x86 it only means a compiler barrier before the update, and making the update to memory, not register, like this:

```
asm volatile("":::"memory");
*(volatile bool*)&m_alreadyCalculated = true;
```

And this is exactly what the atomic set is doing in release semantics