# share read-only data across multiple threads after computing it once in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, sharepoint

I am very new to multi-thread programming and need some pointers on this problem I am having.

I have this object which is expensive to calculate, so what I want to do is calculate it only if needed and once calculated share it with read access if another thread needs it. I only know for which inputs I need the calculations during run time.

So my basic idea was something like this

```
class ExpansiveDoubleCalc
{
    private:
        static double *ptr[10];
        double DoExpansiveCalc(int input)
        {
            double expansivecalc = (123.4 * input);
            return expansivecalc;
        }

    public:
        ExpansiveDoubleCalc(int input, double* output)
        {
            if(ptr[input]==NULL)
                *ptr[input] = DoExpansiveCalc(input);
            output = ptr[input];
        }

};

double * ExpansiveDoubleCalc::ptr[10]{};
```

Lets assume that I only need it for input <10. 
From my little understanding of multi-threading this has numerous problems:
* the threads could try to run DoExpansiveCalc at the same time
* once they get a calculated pointer to output back, it can be slow if multiple threads try to access it

Is that correct? How do I make it safe?
Also, I should probably return a const pointer here right? is there a nice way to do this?

Thanks for the help!! Cheers!

Comment: Is `ExpansiveDoubleCalc()` purely functional? or does it rely on some program state? (btw, the key word you are looking for is **multithreaded memoization**)

Comment: The answer to your question will be found in your C++ book's chapter that explains how to use `std::mutex`es.

Comment: Hi! Thanks @Frank having the right terminalogy is very helpful when searching this kind of stuff.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik do you have a nice C++ book reference for me?

Comment: @Frank actually it will be purely functional! Does that help me? I thought keeping my results in a static array in a class would be nice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36240326/580083. The solution is based on two atomic "flags" (bool variables). Once the calculation is performed, only a single read of one atomic variable is done while accessing calculated data.

Comment: The typical solution would be to either use a mutex (look up `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard<mutex>`, or an array of atomic variables (look up `std::atomic<bool>`). If your expensive calculation is purely functional, you could perform it in more than one thread simultaneously, but I don't see how that would help you. You would still need mutexes or atomic variables to store the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular lock based solution in modern cpp: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/SsQaEB

Some notes:

1. I am setting the size at run time. change to `std::array` if you know the size at compile time.
2. Usually not recommended to use static global state. Use a rawptr or `std::shared_ptr` to share the object explicitly.

---

```
#include<mutex>
#include<vector>

class ExpensiveDoubleCalc {
    public:
    ExpensiveDoubleCalc(size_t size) : data(size){
    }

    static double DoExpensiveCalc(int input) {
        return 123.4 * input;
    }

    double get(int input) {
        return data.at(input).get(input);
    }

    private:
    struct Data {
        bool isSet{false};
        double val;
        std::mutex m;
        double get(int input){
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{m};
            if(isSet){
                return val;
            } else {
                val = DoExpensiveCalc(input);
                isSet = true;
                return val;
            }
        }
    };    
    std::vector<Data> data;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I went with the [Meyers Singleton](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/thread-safe-initialization-of-a-singleton) which holds an array that stores the expensive calculation for each int input, calculating it only if the array entry is not there. If someone is interested I can put together a code example.